# map state is not persisted when using localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, redux, react-redux

I have an app where a user can search for car and see the result. The result page contains results of car along with map(source to destination is shown based on search). When i refresh the page, the state of car results is preserved and it is working well but i get an error for map as invalid latlng and the source to destination route is not shown either. I have used persistedState in redux.

Here is my code

**localstorage.js**

```
export const loadState = () => {
  try {
    const serializedState = localStorage.getItem('state');
    if (serializedState === null) {
      return undefined;
    }
    return JSON.parse(serializedState);
  } catch (err) {
    return undefined;
  }
};

export const saveState = (state) => {
  try {
    const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state);
    localStorage.setItem('state', serializedState);
  } catch (err) {
    // Ignore write errors
  }
};
```

**index.js**

```
store.subscribe(() => {
  saveState({
    getCarResult: store.getState().getCarResult,
    locale: store.getState().locale,
  });
});
```

**car-result.js**

```
function renderMap(cityOrigenLat, cityOrigenLng, cityDestinoLat, cityDestinoLng) {
  return (
        <GoogleMap
          cityOrigenLat={cityOrigenLat}
          cityOrigenLng={cityOrigenLng}
          cityDestinoLat={cityDestinoLat}
          cityDestinoLng={cityDestinoLng}
        />
      );
}

const GoogleMap = ({ cityOrigenLat, cityOrigenLng, cityDestinoLat, cityDestinoLng }) => {
  console.log('cityOrigenLat', cityOrigenLat);
  const position = cityOrigenLat ? [cityOrigenLat, cityOrigenLng] : [51.505, -0.09];
  const icon = divIcon({
    className: 'car-icon',
    iconSize: [50, 50]
  });

  return (
    <Map center={position} zoom={5} style={{ height: 600 }}>
      <TileLayer
        url='https://mt{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}'
        subdomains='0123'
      />
      <Marker position={[cityOrigenLat, cityOrigenLng]} icon={icon} />
      <Marker position={[cityDestinoLat, cityDestinoLng]} icon={icon} />
      <CarRouting from={[cityOrigenLat, cityOrigenLng]} to={[cityDestinoLat, cityDestinoLng]} />
    </Map>
  );
};

class CarResult extends Component {
  render() {
    const { carResult, origen, destino, page, locale } = this.props;
    const cityOrigen = origen && origen.label.split(', ')[0];
    const cityOrigenLat = origen && origen.location.lat; // undefined when refreshing the page 
    const cityOrigenLng = origen && origen.location.lng;
    const cityDestino = destino && destino.label.split(', ')[0];
    const cityDestinoLat = destino && destino.location.lat;
    const cityDestinoLng = destino && destino.location.lng;
    const carResultList = renderCarList(
                          carResult.cars, cityOrigen, cityDestino,
                          startIndex, startCount, perPage, locale
                        );
    const carResultMap = renderMap(cityOrigenLat, cityOrigenLng, cityDestinoLat, cityDestinoLng);
    if (!carResult.fetching) {
      return (
        <div>
          Hemos encontrado {carResultList.length} ofertas para ti.
          <div className="car-result-container">
            <Grid fluid>
              <Row>
                <Col xs={12} sm={12} md={6}>
                  {carResultList}
                </Col>
                <Col x={12} sm={12} md={6} className="kolabooMap">
                  {carResultMap}
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </Grid>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <Grid fluid>
        <Row>
          <Col xs={12} sm={12} md={6}>
            <Row>
              <Col xs={12} sm={12} md={6}>
                loading ...
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
  changePage(page) {
    console.log('page', page);
      this.props.dispatch(push('/car/?page=' + page));
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
     page: Number(state.routing.locationBeforeTransitions.query.page) || 1,
     locale: state.locale
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CarResult);
```

**car-routing.js**

```
class CarRouting extends MapLayer {
  componentWillMount() {
    super.componentWillMount();
    const { map, from, to, ...props } = this.props;
    props.icon = L.divIcon({
        className: 'car-icon',
        iconSize: [50, 50]
    });
    this.leafletElement =
      L.Routing.control({
      position: 'topleft',
      createMarker: () => null,
      waypoints: [
        L.latLng(from[0], from[1]),
        L.latLng(to[0], to[1]),
      ],
    }).addTo(map);
    // L.marker(position, props);
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

export default CarRouting;
```

**result-layout.js**

```
<CarResult
  origen={Origen}
  destino={Destino}
  carResult={carResult}
/>

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    console.log('state', state);
    const carValues = selector(state, 'Origen', 'Destino', 'daterange');
    return {
        carValues,
        carResult: state.getCarResult
    };
  };
```

The problem is when i refresh the page, the result of car is shown(the state is preserved) but routing is not shown in map as i get an error of

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid LatLng object: (undefined, undefined). I get cityOrigenLat undefined during refreshing the page
```

**UPDATE**

```
let cars = [];
const initialState = {
  fetching: false,
  fetched: true,
  cars: [],
  currentPage: 0,
  carsLength: 0,
  error: null
};

export function getCarResult(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'CAR_FETCH_START':
      return { ...state, fetching: true };
    case 'CAR_FETCH_SUCCESS':
      cars = action.payload;
      return {
              ...state,
              fetched: true,
              fetching: false,
              cars: action.payload,
              currentPage: 0,
              carsLength: action.payload.length
             };
    case 'CAR_FETCH_WITH_FILTER':
      return { ...state, fetched: true, fetching: false, cars: carFilterFromPrice(action.payload) };
    case 'CAR_FETCH_WITH_TIME_FILTER':
      return { ...state, fetched: true, fetching: false, cars: carFilterFromTime(action.payload) };
    case 'CAR_FETCH_FAILURE':
      return { ...state, error: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: what is your redux initial state ?

Comment: I dont know which state you are talking about. There is no reducer for map. Reducer is only for car result and i have updated in my question.